# Does MacOS have an equivalent to Windows' Send to/Bluetooth context menu in Explorer?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, file-sharing, finder, send-to

On Windows if I right-click on a file in Explorer, the pop-up context menu has a "Send to..." option which in turn has a Bluetooth option. From here I can send the file directly to my Mac over Bluetooth.

But on my Mac if I control-click on a file in the Finder, the pop-up context menu does have a "Share" option but within it there is no Bluetooth option.

I know I can fire up Bluetooth File Exchange, but then I have to navigate through a file dialog to locate the file I want to send.

Is there some way on the Mac where I can just send a file when I've already got it open right there in the Finder, without having to dig around for its location in a second app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it has AirDrop, but there's no Windows client for it, so I don't think you have a fast way to do this.

BTW, you don't have to 'dig around' for any file you can see on the desktop, just drop it into the file-picker dialog & the dialog will either auto-navigate to that folder or directly handle that file [depending on how the app is coded]. Alternatively, drop the file to the app's icon in the Dock [again, behaviour is app-dependent].

Comment: Well yeah AirDrop is great between my new Mac and my old Mac but it's Apple proprietary. My intuition didn't guide me to trying to drag and drop on the Bluetooth Exchange window but it did indeed work. Thanks!